# What is the use of token tag in Struts2 and how does it work?

Tags: jsp, struts2, token

I came across this `<s:token />` tag and it is enclosed in a `<s:form></s:form>` tag in a JSP Page. 
Some other StackOverflow link discusses its usage in maintaining session and prevention of double submission of forms. What exactly is the use of this tag? If it prevents double submission of form then what happens when I submit form and how does it prevent it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Token Interceptor and Token Session Interceptor?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19525888/1700321)

Comment: @AleksandrM this question/answer doesn't relate with the Struts2 tag, just a piece of code that tells difference but doesn't expain how it works.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: how does it gets to know if it is submitted more than one time, where does the flow go when it checks this, a basic explanation would work :)

Comment: The explanation you are looking for is already [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28717589/1654265), I won't replicate it here, so feel free to upvote that if it helps.

Comment: @AndreaLigios your answer helped to some extent, thnks .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I am answering my own question because this may help someone in future, though I will try to dig more on this and get it updated.

The plain English explanation I found:

> "The token tag generates an unique token which is used to find out whether a form has been double submitted.
>   When the form is rendered, a hidden variable is placed as the token value. Let us say, for example that the token is "ABC". When this form is submitted, the Struts Filter checks the token against the token stored in the session. If it matches, it removes the token from the session. Now, if the form is accidentally resubmitted (either by refreshing or by hitting the browser back button), the form will be resubmitted with "ABC" as the token. In this case, the filter checks the token against the token stored in the session again. But because the token "ABC" has been removed from the session, it will not match and the Struts filter will reject the request." ([Source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_form_tags.htm))

However these two StackOverflow answers add more to knowledge.

- [Difference between Token Interceptor and Token Session Interceptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525888/difference-between-token-interceptor-and-token-session-interceptor)
- [How to avoid inserting two same records twice when double-clicking the submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714011/how-to-avoid-inserting-two-same-records-twice-when-double-clicking-the-submit-bu/28717589#28717589)

Comment: Note: *Struts Filter* should be replaced by **interceptor**.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `<s:token/>` tag:

> Stop double-submission of forms.
>
> The token tag is used to help with the "double click" submission
>   problem. It is needed if you are using the `TokenInterceptor` or the
>   `TokenSessionInterceptor`. The `s:token` tag merely places a hidden
>   element that contains the unique token.

(Source: https://struts.apache.org/docs/token.html )

> What is the use of token tag in Struts2?

See [example](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/a9974eec5689a7113a6fb1e2096252f0935064dd/apps/showcase/src/main/webapp/token/index.html).

> How it works?

It works mainly by using a class, a Helper class and a configuration xml file:
[Token.java](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/a9974eec5689a7113a6fb1e2096252f0935064dd/core/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/components/Token.java) , [TokenHelper.java](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/a9974eec5689a7113a6fb1e2096252f0935064dd/core/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/util/TokenHelper.java), [struts-token.xml](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/a9974eec5689a7113a6fb1e2096252f0935064dd/apps/showcase/src/main/resources/struts-token.xml).